# Passing a parameter to Objects in Lua

Tags: java, lua, textfield

I'm trying to learn Lua

I like to do this (java code):

```
public class Nave {
    private TextField tx;
    public Nave (TextField tx){
        this.tx = tx;
    }   
    public void setMessage (String s){
        this.tx.setText(s);
    }
}

public class SomeClass {
    public static void main (String args[]){
      Nave nave = new Nave (new TextField ("hello world"));

    }
}
```

In Lua; how I pass the TextField to a object?

Comment: In the Java code, you are not passing an object to an object, you are passing an object to a constructor. In Lua, you have to do object orientation on your own, but when you do you typically implement constructors as plain functions (that return the constructed object); and you pass an argument to that function just like to any other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua does not directly have objects.
You can pass it to a function in the same way as in Java, except you can't specify the type.
Just specify that a function takes an object, and then pass it, just like Java.

This should help with OO in Lua. [Lua Objects](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html)

Every data structure in Lua is implemented with a table, so you can put all the data and function into a table and that will function like an object.

I would also recommend reading the entire book, Lua has some things you might not be used to.

```
function newAccount (initialBalance)


local self = {
    balance = initialBalance,
    LIM = 10000.00,
  }

  local extra = function ()
    if self.balance > self.LIM then
      return self.balance*0.10
    else
      return 0
    end
  end

  local getBalance = function ()
    return self.balance + extra()
  end
  local withdraw = function (v)
                     self.balance = self.balance - v
                   end

  local deposit = function (v)
                    self.balance = self.balance + v
                  end

  return {
    withdraw = withdraw,
    deposit = deposit,
    getBalance = getBalance
  }
end
```

this function takes a parameter for initial balance.
It then creates a table that hold the balance and the limit on an option.
Due to closures this table will always be held because the function that are returned as a table contain references to it.

The objects held in self, and the function extra are considered private because they cannot be accessed without a function call, and the methods returned as a table are public methods.

This is pretty close to a java object.
You just have to use some of the Lua rules to make it act like one. i.e. closures and function objects and tables.